# Three JS: OrbitControls вижу скачки пикселей у изображения при перетаскивании

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, drag-n-drop

недавно начал разбираться с 3д, хочу сделать перемещение по сцене, но при перетаскивании вижу как пиксели у картинок начинают прыгать перед остановкой перемещения камеры. Это явно неправильная работа

Почему так происходит? И как этого избежать?
Мой код: https://codepen.io/davedev13/pen/zYEyxRX

```js
const data = {
  "objects": [{
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Creative",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/1",
      "position": {
        "left": "-500",
        "top": "500"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Angles",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/2",
      "position": {
        "left": "500",
        "top": "-500"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Awwards",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/3",
      "position": {
        "left": "500",
        "top": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Conexe",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/4",
      "position": {
        "left": "0",
        "top": "500"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Luxury",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/5",
      "position": {
        "left": "-500",
        "top": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Develop",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/6",
      "position": {
        "left": "0",
        "top": "-500"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Desing",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/7",
      "position": {
        "left": "500",
        "top": "500"
      }
    },
    {
      "img": "https://picsum.photos/400/500",
      "title": "Sociality",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "url": "/8",
      "position": {
        "left": "-500",
        "top": "-500"
      }
    }
  ]
}

class Drag {
  drag = {
    width: 2560,
    height: 1440,
  };
  mouseOut = false;

  constructor(container) {
    this.container = container;
    let w = container.clientWidth;
    let h = container.clientHeight;
    let viewSize = h;
    let aspectRatio = w / h;

    this.viewport = {
      viewSize: viewSize,
      aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
      left: (-aspectRatio * viewSize) / 2,
      right: (aspectRatio * viewSize) / 2,
      top: viewSize / 2,
      bottom: -viewSize / 2,
      near: -10,
      far: 100
    }

    this.initScene();
  }

  initScene() {
    this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
      this.viewport.left, this.viewport.right,
      this.viewport.top, this.viewport.bottom,
      this.viewport.near, this.viewport.far
    );

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      // alpha: true // чтобы сцена была прозрачной
    });

    this.renderer.domElement.id = 'canvasGrid';
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xdcdcdc, 1);

    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    // драг контейнер для сцены
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.drag.width, this.drag.height);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xdcdcdc,
    });
    this.drag.plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // драг бокс по которому гранимац которого будет двигаться сцена при драге
    this.dragBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.drag.plane);

    this.scene.add(this.drag.plane);

    this.sceneObjects();
    this.setControls();
    this.animate();

    window.addEventListener('mouseout', () => this.mouseOut = true, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      this.mouseOut = false;
      this.animate();
    }, false);
  }



  sceneObjects() {
    // instantiate a loader
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    data.objects.map((item) => {
      const group = new THREE.Group();
      group.name = item.title;

      // load a resource
      loader.load(
        // resource URL
        item.img,
        // onLoad callback
        function(texture) {
          const width = texture.image.naturalWidth * 0.5;
          const height = texture.image.naturalHeight * 0.5;

          // in this example we create the material when the texture is loaded
          const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, 0);
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture
          });
          const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

          group.add(mesh);
          group.position.set(item.position.left, item.position.top, 0);
        },

        // onProgress callback currently not supported
        undefined,

        // onError callback
        function(err) {
          console.error('An error happened.', err);
        }
      );

      this.scene.add(group);
    });

    const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(550, 300, 0);
    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*Ynit7J26tXLwyq-sB3AUug.png");
    console.log(texture)
    const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      opacity: 0.3
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    this.scene.add(mesh);
  }

  render() {
    // if (this.mouseDownPressed) {
    let x1 = this.camera.position.x + (this.camera.left / this.camera.zoom);
    let x1a = Math.max(x1, this.dragBox.min.x);
    let pos_x = x1a - (this.camera.left / this.camera.zoom);

    let x2 = pos_x + (this.camera.right / this.camera.zoom);
    let x2a = Math.min(x2, this.dragBox.max.x);
    pos_x = x2a - (this.camera.right / this.camera.zoom);

    let y1 = this.camera.position.y + (this.camera.bottom / this.camera.zoom);
    let y1a = Math.max(y1, this.dragBox.min.y);
    let pos_y = y1a - (this.camera.bottom / this.camera.zoom);

    let y2 = pos_y + (this.camera.top / this.camera.zoom);
    let y2a = Math.min(y2, this.dragBox.max.y);
    pos_y = y2a - (this.camera.top / this.camera.zoom);

    this.camera.position.set(pos_x, pos_y, this.camera.position.z);
    this.camera.lookAt(pos_x, pos_y, this.controls.target.z); // todo: what is it?
    this.controls.target.set(pos_x, pos_y, 0);
    this.controls.update();
    // }

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  setControls() {
    // Need to be similar to what is in OrbitControls3Dpane.js constructor
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.mouseButtons = {
      LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN,
      MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
      RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
    // Set rotate related parameters
    //////////////////////////////////////
    // No rotation.
    this.controls.enableRotate = false;
    this.controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    this.controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    // No orbit horizontally.
    this.controls.minAzimuthAngle = 0; // radians
    this.controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 0; // radians


    //////////////////////////////////////
    // Set zoom related parameters
    //////////////////////////////////////
    this.controls.enableZoom = true;
    this.controls.zoomSpeed = 0.9;
    this.controls.minDistance = this.camera.near;
    this.controls.maxDistance = this.camera.far;
    this.controls.minZoom = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ?
      window.innerWidth / this.drag.width : window.innerHeight / this.drag.height;
    this.controls.maxZoom = 1 + this.controls.minZoom;

    //////////////////////////////////////
    // Set pan related parameters
    //////////////////////////////////////
    this.controls.enablePan = true;
    this.controls.panSpeed = 0.6;
    this.controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
    this.controls.enableDamping = true;

    // this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    //  this.mouseDownPressed = true;
    // }, false);

    // this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    //  setTimeout(() => {
    //      this.mouseDownPressed = false;
    //  }, 700);
    // }, false);
  }

  animate() {
    this.render();

    if (!this.mouseOut) {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  new Drag(document.querySelector('.canvas'));
}

init();
```

```css
.canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="canvas"></div>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://threejs.org/build/three.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antialias: true зарешал у WebGLRenderer

при все тех же настройках сразу сцена плавнее стала и картинки не багуют

тe понизил перфоменс и этим вырулил...